# How to sort by date the nsmutabledictionary

Tags: ios, json, sorting, nsmutabledictionary

I have a JSON returned NSMutabledictionary that contains the following

> 

```
OdometerStart = "9 miles";
    Size = 40;
    StartTime = "01-30-2013 2:30 PM";
    Tractor = T04;

  OdometerStart = "668 miles";
    Size = 40;
    StartTime = "01-30-2013 2:23 PM";
    Tractor = T04;
```

I need to sort it by StartTime, is there a way to sort this?
thanks.

Comment: This looks like an array of dictionaries. You should try pasting in the actual JSON, or the actual output from printing this structure from lldb, so people can know for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to make a sort. This is one :

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict; //dictionary to be sorted

        NSArray *sortedKeys = [dict keysSortedByValueUsingComparator: ^(id obj1, id obj2) {
            //get the key value.
            NSString *s1 = [obj1 objectForKey:@"StartTime"];
            NSString *s2 = [obj2 objectForKey:@"StartTime"];

            //Convert NSString to NSDate:
            NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
            //Set the AM and PM symbols
            [dateFormatter setAMSymbol:@"AM"];
            [dateFormatter setPMSymbol:@"PM"];
           //Specify only 1 M for month, 1 d for day and 1 h for hour
           [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss a"]; 
           NSDate *d1 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:s1];
           NSDate *d2 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:s2];
           [dataFormatter release];

            if ([d1 compare:d2] == NSOrderedAscending) 
                return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
            if ([d1 compare:d2] == NSOrderedDescending)
                return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending; 
            return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
        }];
        NSArray *sortedValues = [[dict allValues] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

take a look in apple documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/Dictionaries.html

sorting descriptor apple documentation here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/SortDescriptors/Articles/Creating.html

Comment: where will i pass the StartTime?

Comment: just get key value and make your own comparison. Hope this help you.